# Is angularjs work client side?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page built-with angular functionality,
It is works fine from xampp server `(http://localhost/...)` but It didn't work from my desktop.

Please let me know AngularJS work from client-side like HTML / Java Script.

Comment: You need to install your application on a web server

Comment: In chrome browser it won't work by clicking directly, you need to start it on a server. In other browsers you can try by just double clicking your html file

Answer (score 3):

Yes, AngularJS (v1 and v2) is a JavaScript framework which only works on the client side.

https://angularjs.org/

For the Server side, you can take a look at Node.JS which works perfectly with AngularJS.

https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works on client side. However, you need to install webserver, to run the app. Take a look at node.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Angular JS works on client side but you can't call REST API Services without Server.

Answer (score 1):

> AngularJS fits the definition of a framework the best, even though
>   it's much more lightweight than a typical framework and that's why
>   many confuse it with a library.
>
> AngularJS is 100% JavaScript, 100% client-side and compatible with
>   both desktop and mobile browsers. So it's definitely not a plugin or
>   some other native browser extension.

About the client side browser support

> We run our extensive test suite against the following browsers: the
>   latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Safari for iOs, as
>   well as Internet Explorer versions 9-11. See Internet Explorer
>   Compatibility for more details on supporting legacy IE browsers.
>
> If a browser is untested, it doesn't mean it won't work; for example,
>   older Android (2.3.x) is supported in the sense that we avoid the dot
>   notation for reserved words as property names, but we don't actively
>   test changes against it. You can also expect browsers to work that
>   share a large part of their codebase with a browser we test, such as
>   Opera > version 12 (uses the Blink engine), or the various Firefox
>   derivatives.